# Solution to paired exponential growth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I have a pair of equations such that:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = x ( r_x + \alpha y) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = y ( r_y + \beta x)
$$

where $r_x , \alpha, r_y \ \text{and} \ \beta$ are constants. I want to find the general solution (i.e. $x(t)$ and $y(t)$) of these equations.
So far been I unable to solve them and I'm not sure how to get a general solution or if such a solution exists.

Comment: $r_y$ and $r_x$ are constants?

Comment: yes, i should have clarified

Comment: You must differentiate the first and substitute $y'$ from the second. Then you can use the first undifferentiated to eliminate $y$.

Comment: Your equations $x(t) = \ldots$ and $y(t) = \ldots$ are wrong.  You can't solve the equation for $x$ by treating $y$ as a constant.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the original question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, take it as a hint.

Starting from:

$$
x' = x ( r_x + \alpha y) \\
y' = x ( r_y + \beta y)
$$

Differentiate the first:

$$
x'' = x' ( r_x + \alpha y) + x \alpha y'
$$  and eliminate $y'$

$$
x'' = x' ( r_x + \alpha y) + \alpha x^2 ( r_y + \beta y)
$$

Now solve $y$ from the first:

$$
y=\frac{1}{ \alpha}\frac {x'}{ x}- r_x 
$$

So

$$
x'' = x' ( r_x (1-\frac{1}{ \alpha})+ \frac {x'}{ x}  ) + \alpha x^2 ( r_y +\frac{ \beta}{ \alpha}\frac {x'}{ x}- \beta r_x )
$$

Now, you can solve it... maybe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I realised I had made a mistake in the original question and mixed up the 2nd equation. I've now corrected it in the original post

Comment: Ok... So look here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka–Volterra_equations

Comment: would I be right in thinking that this means there is no general solution (i.e. $x(t)$ and $y(t)$) ?

Comment: As you can see on Wikipedia there are easy to find implicit equations $f(x,y)$=0$. With some work you can find a parameterization related to time.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
With the new second equation,
$$ x = \dfrac{y'}{\beta y} - \dfrac{r_y}{\beta} $$
and then
$$y'' = - \alpha r_y y^2 + (\alpha y' - r_x r_y) y + r_x y' + (y')^2/y $$
and
$$ t + c_1 = \int \dfrac{dy}{y r_y \left(W\left(c_2 y^{r_x/r_y} \exp( \alpha y/r_y)\right)+1\right)} $$
where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I realised I had made a mistake in the original question and mixed up the 2nd equation. I've now corrected it in the original post